# How do I limit access to a service/port by IP address?

Tags: iptables, ufw

I'm running something on port 3000 and I want to offer this service on port 3000 only to specific users (by IP address). How do I do that?

Is that done with ufw or iptables (both of which I know very little about)?

Answer (score 0):

This answer uses iptables only. ufw is just a front end for iptables, and lots of people like it, I don't.

If you have some iptables rules already, rules from this answer will have to be somehow be added to what already exists. Change the interface name to your interface name.

This answer assumes your list of allowed users is small and that the protocol is tcp. Lists of thousands of ip addresses should be handled via the ipsec extension.

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i enp3s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -s 1.2.3.4 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i enp3s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -s 4.3.2.1 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i enp3s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -s 1.2.4.3 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i enp3s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -s 111.222.113.224 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i enp3s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -j DROP
```

Now, check the resulting rule set:

```
doug@s18:~$ sudo iptables -v -x -n -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 95 packets, 9490 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  enp3s0 *       1.2.3.4              0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3000
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  enp3s0 *       4.3.2.1              0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3000
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  enp3s0 *       1.2.4.3              0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3000
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  enp3s0 *       111.222.113.224      0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3000
       0        0 DROP       tcp  --  enp3s0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3000

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 32 packets, 4916 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Now, test it from another computer. I'll use hping3, but readers might have other preferred utilities. I'll spoof one IP address that is allowed (in my case, no reply because I don't actually have anything listening on port 3000, and because I spoofed the source IP address the reply wouldn't be routed back to the source computer anyhow) and one that isn't:

```
doug@s15:~$ sudo hping3 -c 5 -a 1.2.3.4 --destport 3000 s18
HPING s18 (br0 192.168.111.122): NO FLAGS are set, 40 headers + 0 data bytes

--- s18 hping statistic ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.0/0.0/0.0 ms
doug@s15:~$
doug@s15:~$ sudo hping3 -c 5 -a 4.4.4.4 --destport 3000 s18
HPING s18 (br0 192.168.111.122): NO FLAGS are set, 40 headers + 0 data bytes

--- s18 hping statistic ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.0/0.0/0.0 ms
doug@s15:~$
```

Now, check the paths taken by observing the packet counter in the iptables rule set (hint: exactly as expected):

```
doug@s18:~$ sudo iptables -v -x -n -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 274 packets, 28567 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       5      200 ACCEPT     tcp  --  enp3s0 *       1.2.3.4              0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3000
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  enp3s0 *       4.3.2.1              0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3000
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  enp3s0 *       1.2.4.3              0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3000
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  enp3s0 *       111.222.113.224      0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3000
       5      200 DROP       tcp  --  enp3s0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3000

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 60 packets, 10628 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```